# Uninstall the Encrypted LVM function to remove the prompted password entry during Ubuntu Boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, lvm, encryption

When I installed Ubuntu 11.04 and I was offered the option of enabling "encrypted LVM" for my hard drive. After choosing that option, I am prompted for my password during boot to decrypt the LVM.

Now, I am thinking about cancell/uninstall/remove "encrypted LVM' function as I don't want to input the "encrypted LVM" password every time when the system reboot. I know that you can setup a SSH to decrypt the LVM but that requires the installation of other programs. Is there a better/clean way to solve this problem like just uninstall the "encrypted LVM"? How to do it and this question is NOT specific to Ubuntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no simple "remove encryption" command that will preserve your data.
The [Arch Wiki explains how to remove encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Removing_System_Encryption) and basically it describes the process of data backup, remove encryption, format fs, restore data.

If you entered a long key, and you're tired of typing it every time you login, you could add a new, shorter key.

Before you do any of the following you need to enter your key and backup the unencrypted data.

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/mapper/encrypted
Enter any passphrase: current_key_needs_to_be_entered 
Enter new passphrase for key slot: new_short_key
Verify passphrase:  new_short_key
```

Your new passphrase can be short, just a few chars, 123 if you wish.

This can be done quickly, but leaves the data encrypted with a short useless key.
I would recommend following the wiki and eliminating the encryption.